# SharePoint OnPremise 2013. Workflow on item change infinite loop question

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am worried that I will create an infinite loop. Please let me know if this does.

I have workflow 1 that triggers automatically when a new item is added to library A.(this item is added by submitting an infopath form). The user will get an email linking to editing properties of that item, where they will be asked to insert their supervisor "Supervisor field" , and then click save.

I have Workflow 2 that starts when an item is changed in Library A still. I then have a check to see if the Supervisor field is empty.

```
 If variable:SupervisorField is empty
     ... do nothing
 else
    copy document to Library B, and do some more things

Transition to stage
go to end of workflow.
```

Does adding an item count as changed?
Does updating the status to completed change the item?

Answer (score 0):

Workflow can be associated to List. And during association we can set on what event the workflow should be invoked.

1. Manually
2. On Item Create
3. On Item Update

So in your case Workflow#1 should be only set to start on Item Create and Workflow#2 should be only set to start on Item Update.

On Update Workflow#1 will not get invoked and vice versa.

Comment: I'm hearing differently. Because workflow #2 will update the status everytime, thus changing the list... refiring workflow #2 over and over.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Watch-this-Run-a-workflow-when-a-specific-field-changes-0ca39584-8575-46cf-b551-961d46fff6ce?CorrelationId=2f851587-84ce-46cf-b95d-8187c0955ec6&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US